# Complex Valued Logistic Regression

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, complex-numbers

I'm trying to figure out how to create a complex valued neural network based on the work done in this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09792.

I'm not sure how to even get started (having trouble understanding the math).  I want to just do simple logistic regression rather than RNN or CNN.  Any support/direction/code would really help me out a lot.

Thanks

Comment: although this is a great question, and I am having fun looking at this paper. This is not a good question for stackoverflow. It either needs to be reformatted or you could try on Cross Validated

Comment: I'm glad you like it.  I'm having fun with it too.